# Exception: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure NULL

Tags: php, api, paypal

Suddenly paypal got error on paypal which is working before. I use RESTFUL API library from paypal.

```
Exception: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure NULL
```

Comment: Updating to the latest version of REST API SDKs of respective language could help you resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this could be due to the SSL issue, which PayPal has disable the SSLv3 support completely on January 12th due to Poodle vulnerability.

All information on the POODLE vulnerability and the changes needed can be found here:

[PayPal SSL 3.0 (POODLE) - Merchant Response Guide](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/445843/1417414724/redirect/1/filename/Poodle%20SSL%203%200%20Vulnerability%20-%20Merchant%20Response%20Guide%20(U.S.%20English).pdf)

You can check the status and update your SDK (If needed) here:

[PayPal SSL 3.0 (POODLE) Microsite ACT NOW](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1182)